# Determining if a given user is in a given global group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, dsquery

I’m trying to search through Active Directory using the AD module in PowerShell. I’m trying to determine whether a given user is in a given global group. The issue is that I’m using `-match` meaning if there is a username that contains another within it, such as 'smith_pl' containing 'smith_p'. The user 'smith_p' will be shown to be in the group.

So my question is: Is there a better way of getting a `$True` or `$False` return depending if a user is in a giving global group using the AD module?

**If not**

Is there a way of getting the output from `$ListOfmembers` into an array so I can use `-eq` instead of `-match`?

---

**Part of Script:**

```
$ListOfmembers = dsquery group domainroot -name $globalgroup | 
                 dsget group -members | 
                 dsget user -samid -L

$checkMember = $False
#Search if the user is in output the list
If($ListOfmembers -match $Logonname){
    $checkMember = $True
}
```

**ListOfmembers Output:**

```
samid: user05_t

samid: user23_s

samid: Admin

samid: user45_s

dsget succeeded
```

Any help would be appreciated, Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement")
$username = "samaccountname"
$ct = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
$user = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($ct, $username)
$g =  $user.GetGroups()
( $g | select -expa name ) -contains 'groupname'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$member = Get-ADGroupMember group1 -Recursive | where {$_.samaccountname -eq 'user1'}
if($member) {'user 1 is a member of group1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout QAD: http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx

$user get-qaduser samAccountName
$user.memberof